# jquery mobile form input field resize weirdly if i minimize the browser too small

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

i understand that jquery mobile is responsive with it's widget, but this is one problem i have had for days that idk how to solve it,

each form input i want it to have a image at the left side and a input field at the right as seen in this fiddle i made

http://jsfiddle.net/L4q7C/1/

the code:

```
<form id="signUpForm">
<div>
    <div class="ui-field-contain">
        <label for="input-fullName">
            <img src="simages/User-Role-Administrator-icon.png" id="user">
        </label>
        <input class="form-contact" type="text" name="input-fullName" id="input-fullName" value="" placeholder="Full Name">
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

if u minimize it it will resize nicely until u resize it to be quite small u can see the input field will go under the image. I am merely using the jquery mobile css now and it is giving me a problem for me to continue doing this for my app. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working fiddle where they stay on the same line: http://jsfiddle.net/L4q7C/3/

**HTML:**

```
<form id="signUpForm"> 
    <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
        <div class="ui-block-a"><img src="simages/User-Role-Administrator-icon.png" id="user"/></div>
        <div class="ui-block-b"><input class="form-contact" type="text" name="input-fullName" id="input-fullName" value="" placeholder="Full Name"/> </div>    
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: good idea! why didn't i thought of using this at all.. silly me, let me try it out on my side. BTW do you think it's the mobile css style that are causing the resizing problem?